# Direct download link

Tags: .net, iis

I am running a .net app locally through IIS.  The app is an API app which gets published a local folder c:\web\ and accessed via a url I have setup: https://localhost:4343/

This works great so far.

I have also created a folder in c:\web where I store static documents. The full path to this folder is c:\web\Resources\Attachments\

I would like to be able to access files in this folder directly through the browser, using a url such as:

https://localhost:4343/Resources/Attachments/test.pdf

But it always returns a 404.

How can set these direct links up as they would be on a normal web server?  I would like to avoid having to process anything from within the .net app itself.

Comment: Enable detailed error pages for your site in IIS and provide more detailed error messages (Includes 404 sub-status codes) for us. Or try using FRT to view details about the 404 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was to assume a physical path relative to my site folder would be accessible via the url as it would be under web servers such as Apache.

The solution was to create a virtual directory in IIS Manager and map that to the folder I wanted access to via url.